# Wrong information on asking of questions page when my account is blocked from asking of question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, rate-limiting

If I [ask a question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and my account is blocked from asking question it says `You've asked 3 questions recently` where in reality if you [take a look at my profile](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/144875/cary-bondoc) you can only see 2 question with so much down vote that nobody cares to explain to me why.

> You have reached your question limit It looks like you might need a
>   break - take a breather and come back soon!
>
> You've asked 3 questions recently, some of which have not been
>   received very well by the community. Everyone learns at their own
>   pace, and it’s okay to make some mistakes. However, the reception your
>   questions have received thus far might ultimately block your account
>   from asking questions entirely.
>
> It's been 0 days since you asked your last question. We ask that you
>   wait 7 days before asking again. Use this time to revisit your
>   previous questions, editing to address any issues that folks have
>   pointed out in comments.

Answer (score 2):

> you can only see 2 question

First off, do you have any deleted questions? These don't show on the profile, and if the question was asked recently you should be able to go to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/144875 to see this.  Otherwise, you would need to get a mod to pull out a link to any other deleted posts that you have.

---

> with so much down vote that nobody cares to explain to me why.

[Difference between admin and super admin?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/298097/difference-between-admin-and-super-admin) is a rather boring and uninteresting terminology question. No, there is no standard for 95% of any of the words we use in programming. Even 'bug' has no standard definition.  The name of a role has no standard definition either.

The mouseover for a down vote reads:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

Your question does not show any research effort.  It is not useful.

Likewise, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/297056/is-commenting-of-code-part-of-system-documentation is a question of definitions again.

> When my boss says that I need to have a proper documentation of the project does it include proper commenting of codes in my project?

As I pointed out in the comments, "Ask your manager."  The question is either to be closed as a duplicate (of something that many people are tired of having questions and attempts at debates on), or primary opinion. The question does not show any attempt at searching for our well known answers, and again attempts to stir up a useless debate. Thus, the question was down voted.

I would encourage you to read [Why was my question down voted?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6488/)  The [help center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is also a good read about the types of questions that are in scope. Make sure you completely read the text paragraphs at the end and not just the bullet points.

Comment: Yes, I have deleted question. Thank you for the clarification

Comment: [What is the meaning of programaticaly?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/291878/31260) - closed, deleted, at -4 and _answered_, which is supposed to be [heavier penalized by blocking heuristics](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168835/165773)